# How to find a file using MDD Library for PIC32

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, pic32, mdd

I have a PIC32 microcontroller with a SD Card attached to my design and I'm using the MDD library to implement an algorithm in order to find a specific file in the SD CARD.

Is there someone, who can guide/tell me, which function should I use?

Comment: Did I ask something stupid to be marked as -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the FindFirst/FindNext functions to search for files. If you need to find a file in a directory tree you can call your own search function recursively:

- FindFirst for all files `(*.*)`, if first found file matches the file you're looking for - return result
- FindNext in a loop...
- If a file matches - return result
- If you find a directory, set the current working directory to that directory and call your searchfunction recursively
- If you find no more files - return failure